# cannot load image from the local storage using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am a beginner and trying to load local image using json on the browser.
I have 3 questions for this code:

```js
var jsonString = '[{"1":"/models/view/css/pics/dipesh.jpg","2":"/models/view/css/pics/ashish.jpg","3":"/models/view/css/pics/prasun.jpg"}]';

localStorage.setItem("1", jsonString);
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("1"));
$(".player").click(function() {
  var img = new Image(150, 150);
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    img.setAttribute("src", obj[i][1]);
    document.getElementById(img).style.borderRadius = "8px";
    $("#my").html(img);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="shape" id="my"></div>
```

my 1st question is:

1. If I use web path its working. But it shows only 1st image.It is not loading other images.
2. Therefore I used localStorage to use local image path but its not working.It shows this error:

   GET http://localhost:8080/undefined 404 (Not Found)
3. Question no.3 is, it is not setting the border radius of the image.nad showing this error:

   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Can anybody help me?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: JSON.stringify(jsonString); are you not trying to convert something to JSON which is already in JSON ? :P

Comment: @Vikrant : I have already tried it. Its not working

Comment: @argentum47 : Ohh.. yes, thnx. I removed that line but still the same output.

Comment: @gotchha check my answer and updated fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see updated code on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/23tfq2pe/5/)

```
   var jsonString = '[{"1":"https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png","2":"https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png","3":"https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png"}]';
   localStorage.setItem("1", jsonString);
   var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("1"));

   $(".player").click(function() {  
      $.each(obj[0],function(key,value){
       var img = new Image(150, 150); 
       img.setAttribute("src", value);
       img.style.borderRadius = "8px";
      $("#my").append(img);
     });
   });
```

Comment: Yes its working with remote location. I need it to work with local files.

Comment: @gotchha you can set your local image url :)

Comment: I am trying to set local path but its shows 404 for the image. can you please tell me which is correct path?
I have added my directory structure.
```GamePlayer/models/view/css/pics/dipesh.jpg
GamePlayer/models/view/css/js/myjs.js```

I have parallel dir pics and js

Comment: thnx for it but I am asking for local path. Its working for remote files but its not working with local files.

Comment: @gotchha  you can assing full page using window.location.hostname . it will give you host name  so try like  "http://"+window.location.hostname+"projectdirectory"+path .. this will work if you use php local host otherwise you need to show me your directory strecture

Comment: I have given a directory structure above in comment-3

Comment: yeah its working with localhost path. millions of thanx to you.!!

Answer (score 4):

Your data is an array with just an object at first index. And it's already JSON :

```
var jsonString = '[{"1":"/models/view/css/pics/dipesh.jpg","2":"/models/view/css/pics/ashish.jpg","3":"/models/view/css/pics/prasun.jpg"}]';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

for(var key in jsonObj[0]) {
  console.log(jsonObj[0][key])
}
```

Comment: Its printing in console but not loading on browser

Comment: yes I tried it with append.html function but its not loading. can you please give me an example in fiddle?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I got the answer. I used ```"http://"+window.location.hostname+"projectdirectory"+path .``` and its working now

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.parseJSON` instead as follows,

```
var jsonString = '[{"1":"/models/view/css/pics/dipesh.jpg","2":"/models/view/css/pics/ashish.jpg","3":"/models/view/css/pics/prasun.jpg"}]';
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);

for(var key in obj[0]) {
  console.log(obj[0][key])
}
```